# Strip empty values from form inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I have couple of default elements in my Schema. When submitting a form with an empty inputs, Mongoose doesn't apply the default value. I tried setting the Input to false before sending, but all I get is false as a value after submiting. Here's is how I tried:

```
addPermitForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault;
  addPermitInput.forEach((input) => {
    if(input.value == '') input.value = false;
  });
  e.target.submit();
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: This question at this point has nothing to do with any back end code or a database. All you are asking right now is how to strip any blank input fields on a form from being sent in the submission. You can ask that, but I would strongly advise against the practice. If you expect "defaults" then these "should" be presented to the user as expected values "in the form itself". It's really bad practice to do things behind the scenes and not inform the user. If this is "additional defaults", then these should not be presented fields on the front end in the first place.

Comment: `input.value = false;` input values are strings not boolean

Comment: Ok so I found a way around this - I removed the name value before sending to the Server.

Comment: @NeilLunn I will add some helper text next to the Input fileds. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found a way around this - I removed the name value before sending to the Server.

```
addPermitForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  addPermitInput.forEach((input) => {
    if(input.value == '') input.name = '';
  });
  e.target.submit();
});
```